# stop SQL service in c#

Tags: c#, sql, service

I have installed 2 servers for Microsoft SQL 2008. The first one is MSSQLSERVER and second one is SQL2008. When I tried to stop the first one it stopped but the second one not the VS told me that this service not found

```
ServiceController svc =
    new ServiceController("SQL2008", Process.GetCurrentProcess().MachineName);
svc.Stop()
```

So, how can I stop the second one also ?

Comment: Assuming that "SQL22088" is a cut-and-paste error and that "SQL2008" is what actually appears in your code?

Comment: yes sorry for this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the command prompt, type NET START to get a list of running services.  The name you see listed is what you should pass as the first argument.  A example name would be "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)".

Comment: "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is a display name and is different to the actual service name, but net start will enumerate it though

Answer (score 0):

I can't access a SQL box just now but the service name is something like `mssqlserver$2008` IIRC

If you find the service in services.msc, double click, it's the top label/entry. This is the actual servicename in the registry (HKLM) and would respond to `net start` etc. It's different to the display name.

Hopefully it's the same for c#